# Heap corruption detected | C

Tags: c, console-application

im making a little program in C to make .cpp and .h files for me when i call the program from a console. It's working but when i use the program, after i pressed enter and the files where made, i get a popup error: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED.

can anyone help me out with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <direct.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2 ) {
        printf("Not enough arguments given: usage [name]");
        return;
    }

    char* name=(char*)malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
    name = argv[1];
    char* name2 = (char*)malloc(strlen(name));
    strcpy(name2, name);

    strcat(name, ".cpp");
    strcat(name2, ".h");

    name[strlen(name) + 1] = '\0';
    name2[strlen(name2)+ 1] = '\0';

    FILE * fp = fopen(name, "w");
    FILE * fp2 = fopen(name2, "w");

    free(name);
    free(name2);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: error popup]

Comment: `name = argv[1];` and then you do `free(name)`. You can't `free(argv[1])`, you need to free what `malloc `returned.

Comment: `name = argv[1];`? Do `strcpy(name, argv[1]);` instead. Also, in those allocations, include extra space for the `strcat`.

Comment: Don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. You need to allocate space for the null-terminator as well (it's not counted by `strlen`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not allocate enough long in

> ```
> char* name=(char*)malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
> name = argv[1];
> char* name2 = (char*)malloc(strlen(name));
> strcpy(name2, name);
>
> strcat(name, ".cpp");
> strcat(name2, ".h");
> ```

because you need space for ".cpp" and ".h" without forgetting the null terminating char, so a solution can be :

```
size_t alen = strlen(argv[1]);
char * h = malloc(alen + 3);
char * cpp = malloc(alen + 5);

strcpy(h, argv[1]);
strcpy(h + alen, ".h");
strcpy(cpp, argv[1]);
strcpy(cpp + alen, ".cpp");
```

and somewhere free *h* and *cpp*

In

> ```
> name[strlen(name) + 1] = '\0';
> name2[strlen(name2)+ 1] = '\0';
> ```

you already suppose having the null terminating char to be able to use *strlen*. (of course these lines do not exist using my proposal above)

In

> ```
> free(name);
> ```

you free  `argv[1]` and you cannot.  (of course your two initial free do not exist using my proposal above)

In

> ```
> if (argc < 2 ) {
>     printf("Not enough arguments given: usage [name]");
>     return;
> }
> ```

you return nothing, an *int* is expected

You need also to check the *fopen* success, and also the *malloc* even we generally have enough memory for a program requiring few memory

---

Your *main* can be :

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2 ) {
        printf("Not enough arguments given: usage %s [name]\n", *argv);
        return -1;
    }

    size_t alen = strlen(argv[1]);
    char * h = malloc(alen + 3);
    char * cpp = malloc(alen + 5);

    if ((h == NULL) || (cpp == NULL)) {
      puts("not enough memory");
      return -1;
    }

    strcpy(h, argv[1]);
    strcpy(h + alen, ".h");
    strcpy(cpp, argv[1]);
    strcpy(cpp + alen, ".cpp");

    FILE * fph = fopen(h, "w");

    if (fph == NULL) {
      printf("cannot open %s\n", h);
      return -1;
    }

    FILE * fpcpp = fopen(cpp, "w");

    if (fcpp == NULL) {
      printf("cannot open %s\n", cpp);
      return -1;
    }


    free(h);
    free(cpp);

    /* write in files */

    fclose(fh);
    fclose(fcpp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MaxPrakken do you have that problem when you compile or an error at the execution waying you cannot open the file ?

Comment: thanks for the solution, that works perfectly, and i understand better what im doing right now, i deleted my last comment because im a idiot.

Comment: its was a excecution problem, but it was because in my envoirment settings it was still on release while i was compiling on debug. so thats just stupid on my end, works perfectly now